# Ionic2 components no style after innerHTML

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic2

Here's what i'm trying to do:

I have a string with html and ionic elements in my .ts file:

```
page_content = "<ion-card class='card-ios'><ion-card-header>Header</ion-card-header><ion-card-content>Card Content</ion-card-content></ion-card>"
```

then i want to inject that string in a div in the html page:

```
<ion-content padding class="home">
<div [innerHTML]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(page_content)">
</div>
</ion-content>
```

the problem is that the style of the card is not applied to the content, if i insert the code directly in the html it shows fine.

**with innerHTML**

[image]

**inserted directly**

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Angular2 doesn't compile innerHtml you have to use DynamicComponentLoader